# WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document - error appears only after added scheduller

Tags: spring, dom, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I created an application based on Spring Batch which basically has a custom itemreader for reading a folder searching for candidate files, a custom itemprocessor for reading the file and transforming it in diferente file and a custom itemwriter in order to delete the file. It works as expected with no errors untill I added a scheduller. After I added the scheduller, I get the error pasted in the question topic. I found some questions with similiar issue but very diferente context. The must strange point is that, in fact, even though I see such error on console, it is working. I mean, the folder is read (itemreader), the file is transformed (itemprocessor) and the input file is deleted (itemwriter).
I am very confused. If either I could reproduce the error without the scheduller, then I could focus on some node or I had not get the result after I introduced the scheduller so I could focus in some possible error in my scheduller configuration but both aren't the case. Any suggestion will be appreciatted.

The next paragraph was added on January 10th:

After depeer investigation, I found that such error happens only once and only with the main thread. I mean, if I have a candidate file when I start my application, then I get WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR. Let's say, I start my application with no files available to be found by CustomItemReader, wait until the main thread finishes, then I place a candidate file to be found by CustomItemReader, there will be no error at all. In other words, when CustomItemReader is triggered by pool-2-thread-1 and find a file it works correctly. On other hands, when CustomItemReader is triggered by main thread and find a file, which happens only during application startup, it causes the issue.
By using JConsole, I can check that the main thread has gone and the pool-2-thread-1 is up and running. Then, I add my file in the input folder which causes CustomItemReader to return a String instead of null and there will be no errors. Certainly, I missing certain concept about using Spring Scheduller and Spring Batch together. Obviously, I want my application to raise no errors if I start it and it finds the file soon it initialize. Why does it only happen during main thread but if I took Spring Scheduller out it will work as expected one time? Am I missing some synchronization parameter?

The next paragraph was added on January 11th:

I updated only the class where the error happens with larger snippet. All the others remain the same.

```
@Component
public class Queue {

       private Node queue;

       @Autowired
       private Environment env;

       public Element myMethod(String file) {
              //...
              DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
              DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
              Document d = docBuilder.parse(env.getProperty("certainFile.xml"));

              Element template = d.getDocumentElement();
              queue = d.createElement("c:file");
              ((Element) queue).setAttribute("xmlns:c", "myApp");

              queue.appendChild(queue.getOwnerDocument().importNode(template, true));

              template = (Element) queue.getLastChild();

              addField(template, "someFieldLabel");
       }

       private void addField(Element message, String field) {

              // ....

              Element newField = queue.getOwnerDocument().createElement(field);

              for (int k = 0; k < certainList.getLength(); k++) {

                     if ("...certain logic") {
                           newField = (Element) queue.getOwnerDocument().importNode(fieldFormat, true);

                           if ("...other logic"){
                                  newField.setAttribute("manual", "true");
                           }
                           newField.removeAttribute("indicator");
                           break;

                     }
              }
              for (int j = 0; j < fields.getLength(); j++) {
                     Element e = (Element) (fields.item(j));
                     if (e.getNodeName().equals(fieldType)) {
                           // some cascades "ifs"
                           // the error happens in next line but only in the main thread
                           message.insertBefore(newField, e);
                           // let's ignore the rest
                     }
              }
       }
```

//----

```
@Configuration

@ComponentScan("com.example") 

@EnableBatchProcessing

@EnableAutoConfiguration

@EnableScheduling

@PropertySource(value="classpath:config.properties")

@PropertySource(value="classpath:ipm.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound=true)

public class BatchConfiguration {



       @Autowired

       private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;



       @Autowired

       private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;



       @Bean

       public Step step1(ItemReader<String> reader, ItemProcessor<String, String> processor, ItemWriter<String> writer) {

              return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<String, String> chunk(1)

                           .reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer).allowStartIfComplete(true)

                           .build();

       }



       @Bean

       public ItemProcessor<String , String> processor(){

              return new CustomItemProcessor();

       }



       @Bean

       public ItemWriter<String> writer() {

              return new CustomItemWriter();



       }



       @Bean

       public Job job(Step step1) throws Exception {

              return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")

                           .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1).build();

       }



       @Bean

       @StepScope

       public ItemReader<String> reader() {

              return new CustomItemReader();



       }



}
```

//-----

```
public class CustomItemReader implements ItemReader<String> {



       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory

                     .getLogger(CustomItemReader.class);



       @Autowired

       private Environment env;



       @Override

       public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,

                     ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {



              String[] stringArray;

              try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(env

                           .getProperty("myFile")))) {

                     stringArray = stream.map(String::valueOf)

                                  .filter(path -> path.endsWith("out"))

                                  .toArray(size -> new String[size]);



              }



              if (stringArray.length > 0) {

                     log.info("read method - file found");

                     return stringArray[0];

              } else {

                     log.info("read method - no file found");

                     return null;



              }

       }



}
```

//----

```
public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String , String> {



       @Autowired

       @Qualifier(value="queue")

       private Queue q;



       @Autowired

       private Environment env;



       @Override

       public String process(String s) throws Exception {



              q.myMethod();



              return s;            

       }



}
```

//----

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {



       @Override

       public void write(List<? extends String> s) throws Exception {



       Path path1 = Paths.get(s, “notImportantDetail”);



java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(path1);



       }



}
```

//----

```
@Component

public class QueueScheduler {



       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory

                     .getLogger(QueueScheduler.class);



    private Job job;

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;



    @Autowired

    public QueueScheduler(JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("job") Job job){

        this.job = job; 

        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;

   }







   @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)

   public void runJob(){

          try{

       jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

          }catch(Exception ex){

                 log.info(ex.getMessage());

          }

   }

}
```

//----

:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-08 14:51:44.783  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on GH-VDIKCISV252 with PID 7716 (C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\demo\target\classes started by e049447 in C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\demo)

2016-01-08 14:51:44.788  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2016-01-08 14:51:44.955  INFO 7716 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e2c9341: startup date [Fri Jan 08 14:51:44 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy

2016-01-08 14:51:50.882  WARN 7716 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.

2016-01-08 14:51:51.030  WARN 7716 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.

2016-01-08 14:51:51.386  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb', username='sa'

2016-01-08 14:51:52.503  WARN 7716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.AbstractListenerFactoryBean    : org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader is an interface.  The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations.  If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listner annotations can be used.

2016-01-08 14:51:53.572  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql]

2016-01-08 14:51:53.667  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 94 ms.

2016-01-08 14:51:54.506  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup

2016-01-08 14:51:54.617  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL

2016-01-08 14:51:54.744  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []

2016-01-08 14:51:54.745  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL

2016-01-08 14:51:54.912  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.

2016-01-08 14:51:54.961  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.

2016-01-08 14:51:55.044  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]

2016-01-08 14:51:55.088  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]

2016-01-08 14:51:55.095  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]

2016-01-08 14:51:55.176  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]

2016-01-08 14:51:55.245  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - collecting the  out file names

2016-01-08 14:51:55.314  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - collecting the  out file names

2016-01-08 14:51:55.440  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - file found

2016-01-08 14:51:55.443  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemProcessor          : process method:

2016-01-08 14:51:55.461  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - file found

2016-01-08 14:51:55.462  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemProcessor          : process method:

2016-01-08 14:51:57.088 ERROR 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step1 in job job1

org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.

```
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:288) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at com.example.Queue.addField(Queue.java:1555) ~[classes/:na]

   at com.example.Queue.addMessagesFromAuth(Queue.java:453) ~[classes/:na]

   at com.example.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:45) ~[classes/:na]

   at com.example.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:1) ~[classes/:na]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]

   at com.example.QueueScheduler.runJob(QueueScheduler.java:33) [classes/:na]

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]

   at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]

   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

2016-01-08 14:51:57.104  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]

2016-01-08 14:51:57.754  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemWriter             : write method: [C:\myApp\from\0000000571900000999674MHlog.txt.out]

2016-01-08 14:51:57.761  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - collecting the  out file names

2016-01-08 14:51:57.762  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - no file found

2016-01-08 14:51:57.783  INFO 7716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

2016-01-08 14:51:57.786  INFO 7716 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 13.693 seconds (JVM running for 14.853)

2016-01-08 14:52:54.724  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]

2016-01-08 14:52:54.750  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]

2016-01-08 14:52:54.755  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - collecting the  out file names

2016-01-08 14:52:54.756  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - no file found

2016-01-08 14:52:54.775  INFO 7716 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

Comment: I do need help on such issue. If some extra information is need, kindly, let me know it.

Comment: who is the creator and where `newField` and `e` are created? maybe it is a problem of shared variable overwriting between different thread created by scheduler

Comment: Luca, I added where newField and e are created so you can see their scope. I am wondering why it only happens with main thread and only when I have both main thread and pool-2-thread-1 running. If I remove schedule there will be no error or if I paste the candidate file after main thread has finished, there will be no error as well. As far as I can see, there is no shared variable between thread at all. But as I am quite new in Spring Batch and Spring Scheduller, maybe, "accidently" I have share them. Which things should I check in order to guarantee there is none shared among threads?

Comment: I am very interested on this question. Any further information, just let me know it.

Comment: Do you need property `queue` in class `Queue`? I think you can solve the error by removing `private Node queue` and use it as a local variable in `myMethod()`. Else you can try to give a fresh instance of `Queue` to every `CustomItemProcessor`. IMHO is just a sort of "concurrency problem" (WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERROR is pretty clear) and need a good session of debugging

Comment: Honestly, I understood that in every thread, regardless it was created by static main method or by spring scheduler, a fresh instance of Queue was given to CustomItemProcessor. Do you mean that the Queue instance pass throw CustomItemProcessor is the same between the main thread and the pool-2-thread-1? If so, how can make it different? Additionally, is that a way to break/avoid/block the main thread to run the job and only the spring scheduller call it? The concurrency only happens when I started the application and I have both main and pool-2-thread-1 running. After main die, no more issues.

Comment: Luca, about your first question, yes, I do need "private Node queue;" inside of Queue class and I can't move this to myMethod because there are other methods called during myMethod flow which uses such global variable. I didn't show it in my short example but in few words, the Node queue is "the most important" variable since it is the purpose of Queue class: it start from scratch and suffer several changes in myMethod, otherMethod, anotherMethod, etc, all them called from same myMethod, until it is ready. For instance, void addField is aimed to add a field in such global Node variable.

Comment: Hi all. I am still looking at this thread often.

Comment: Hello all, I am still looking at this question carefully.